# Norm of a number in an algebraically closed field

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I consider an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero $F$ as a vector space over a real closed field $R \subset F$. I would like to define a norm on $F$ in an invariant fashion, i.e. if we consider another real closed subfield $R' \subset F$ then the norm would still be equivalent to the norm defined taking $R$.

More precisely, for instance for $\mathbb{C}$ we have the norm $N(z)=a^2 +b^2$ where $z=a+ib$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. If we consider $R' \subset \mathbb{C}$ then the same $z \in \mathbb{C}$ will be written as $z=a'+jb'$, $a', b' \in R'$ and $R'$ is a real closed field of index 2 in $\mathbb{C}$. Is the norm $N'(z)=a'^2+b'^2$ equivalent to $N$?

Comment: I don't think so. IIRC $\mathbb{C}$ has lots of wild automorphisms and most of them aren't even measurable, so it would be surprising to me if they did anything reasonable to the norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any norm of a quadratic extension, you can specify the Galois-fixed elements as those $x$  for which $N(x) = x^2$.  If you had an invariant norm, it would imply the real-closed field is unique.  However, (assuming choice) the complex numbers have automorphisms that don't commute with complex conjugation, i.e., that take copies of $\mathbb{R}$ to different subfields.